# Angular 5 must click to continue after HTTP Post request

Tags: angular, angular5

I am working on an Angular 5 component that includes "ngx-file-drop" and "ngx-spinner" modules. 
The issue appears after the upload of a file via my API.
The file is correctly uploaded, and on my subscribe function, it shows correctly the console.log line but not the others, so I have to click on the screen to continue.

in the code below, I tried to add an eventEmitter to handle the and of the upload. It is correctly triggered but the "this.spinner.hide() and this.entryFile = null" are not executed until I click on the screen.

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FileSystemDirectoryEntry, UploadFile, FileSystemFileEntry, UploadEvent } from 'ngx-file-drop';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {NgxSpinnerService} from 'ngx-spinner';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfirmSavedModalContent } from '../../../shared/form/confirm-saved-modal.content';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './import.component.html'
})
export class PoiImportComponent implements OnInit {
  resourceUrl = 'api/files/upload';
  public fileEntry: UploadFile;
  public wrongFileType:boolean;
  public finishReceiver = new EventEmitter();
  constructor( 
    private http: HttpClient,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    public spinner : NgxSpinnerService,
    private translate: TranslateService) {
    var lang = window.sessionStorage.getItem("LANG");
    if (lang !== undefined && lang !== null){
        translate.setDefaultLang(lang);
    }
    else{
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    }
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    //receives the end of the file upload.
    this.finishReceiver.subscribe(resolve=>{
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.fileEntry = null;
    });

  }



  public dropped(event: UploadEvent) {

    //Get file dropped
    var tmp = event.files[0];

    //Split name to get extention
    var name = tmp.relativePath.split(".");

    //Check if the extension is right
    this.wrongFileType = (name[1] !== "csv");
    if (!this.wrongFileType){
      this.fileEntry = tmp;
    }
  }

  //Show alert of wrong file extension
  public fileLeave(event){
   this.wrongFileType = false;
  }

  clearFile(){
    this.fileEntry = null;
    this.hideAlert();
  }

  hideAlert(){
    this.wrongFileType = false;
  }

  uploadFile(){

    //check if the entry is a valid file
    if (this.fileEntry.fileEntry.isFile){

      //Cast entry to file System
      const upload = this.fileEntry.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;

      //Show loading spinner
      this.spinner.show();

      //Get the file from dropped data
      upload.file((file:File)=>{

        //Create formData from the file dropped
        let input = new FormData();
        input.append('name',file.name);
        input.append('file', file);
        this.http.post<File>(this.resourceUrl, input).subscribe(resolve =>{
          //Send finish upload emit
          this.finishReceiver.emit(resolve);
        });
      });
    }else{
      this.spinner.hide();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and check again :

```
 uploadFile(){
    $mainRef = this.
    //check if the entry is a valid file
    if (this.fileEntry.fileEntry.isFile){

      //Cast entry to file System
      const upload = this.fileEntry.fileEntry as FileSystemFileEntry;

      //Show loading spinner
      this.spinner.show();

      //Get the file from dropped data
      upload.file((file:File)=>{
    //Create formData from the file dropped
    let input = new FormData();
    input.append('name',file.name);
    input.append('file', file);
    this.http.post<File>(this.resourceUrl, input).subscribe(resolve =>{
      //Send finish upload emit
      $mainRef.finishReceiver.emit(resolve);
    });
  });
}else{
  this.spinner.hide();
}
```

}

Comment: Tries that, the event is emitted,  I receive it, this.spinner.hide() and this.fileEntry = null are executed according to the debugger. but on the interface nothing happen, the spinner doesn't disappear

Comment: I think there is some other issue.Try to replace $mainRef.finishReceiver.emit(resolve);  with $mainRef.spinner.hide(); $mainRef.fileEntry = null; in your upload function.

Comment: Tried that also, only console.log instructions are executed. I don't understand why

Comment: Can you create stackblitz for your app so I can get better idea about it.

Comment: What part do you need cause my app is really big, I can't  create project for it